# oData - aspnetcore - custom controller routes

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I can use this attribute to custom route aspnetcore api controllers:

```
[Route("test")]
```

but oData won't recognize it.

How can I fix this?

As Requested here is all the code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(mvcOptions => mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddOData();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Select().SkipToken();
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());               
        });
    }

    private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        edmBuilder.EntitySet<DivUser>("Users");
        edmBuilder.EntitySet<DivClaim>("Claims");
        edmBuilder.EntitySet<DivUserRole>("UserRoles");
        edmBuilder.EntitySet<DivUserType>("UserTypes");
        return edmBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<DivUser> Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<DivUser> users;
        using (var context = new DivDbContext())
        {
            users = context.Users.Include(user => user.UserClaims).ThenInclude(userClaim => userClaim.Claim).ToList();
        }

        return users;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route("test")]
    public IEnumerable<DivUser> Test()
    {
        IEnumerable<DivUser> users;
        using (var context = new DivDbContext())
        {
            users = context.Users.Include(user => user.UserClaims).ToList();               
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

https://localhost:44354/users WORKS
https://localhost:44354/users/test WORKS

https://localhost:44354/odata/users WORKS
https://localhost:44354/odata/users/test DOES NOT

Comment: Post full codes including your oData.

Comment: Added the startup.cs and the controller in question.